# com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton button not displaying in design using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Connected Firebase with my Android project and here is my `build.gradle` file code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.seyali_01.firebasegooglein"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In my activity_main.xml this is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.seyali_01.firebasegooglein.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/batman">

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Trying for `google-sign-in` in my project using Firebase but the default `google-signIn` button not displaying after adding the above code but it not showing any error in the xml file. Kindly help me to sort out this problem as i'm new to this platform.

I just want to know if the error comes because of `ConstraintLayout` or mistakes in gradle files kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code in which you are adding the button in your activity. You also can take a look in one of my [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwgMWBhObDw&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=5) where I have explained step by step the exact thing that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this error is due to the bug in Android Studio,

Try this:
    Restart your Android-studio and click File from Menu bar and choose invalidate caches / restart.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I tried this before itself but works this second time thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error is because of the fact that you haven't added the required constraints to that button.
Try adding constraints.